# xml/xsl not loading in IE11. Trying to forcing compatibility mode on xml/xsl page

Tags: html, xml, jsp, internet-explorer, xslt

I have a page that contains xml from an xsl document. It does not work on IE11 (the page is blank. when I view the source, the xml is there) but works on IE8. When I add the site to compatibility mode, this page works fine.

What I need to do is force compatibility mode on this page only. The `ua-compatible` meta tag has not effect. What can I do to force compatibility mode?

```
<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>
<?x-ua-compatible content="IE=Edge"?> //does not work

<% response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8"); %>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xsl/my_xsl.xsl"?>
<c:out value="${xmlDataFromRequest}" escapeXml="Y"/>
```

edit:

I have tried `content="IE=EmulateIE8"` and `content="IE=8"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: You say you want to force compatibility mode, yet you set `<?x-ua-compatible content="IE=Edge"?>`? Why is that?

Comment: @MartinHonnen i have tried `content="IE=EmulateIE8"` and `content="IE=8"` and it doesn't work

Comment: What does F12 and the error console show when the page is blank?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a knowledge base article on this.

> Internet Explorer may not display local XML content

### Symptoms

The XML document loads an XSL or XSLT style sheet from the local Windows file system.

### Resolution

To resolve this problem in Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, or Windows Server 2012, install the most recent cumulative security update for Internet Explorer.

### Further reading

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2974524

Comment: But `<%@ taglib uri='http://java.sun.com/jstl/core' prefix='c' %>` does not look like "local" content loaded from the file system, it is a server-side framework, JSP.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be duplicate xml declarations in the document. IE8 seems to tolerate this where as ie9+ do not.

I was able to see the error message by doing F12 it said something like "xml declaration should be at the start of the document" it was at the start but there was a second declaration below it.

to fix it I simply removed the second declaration.